# Shell-kernel interaction

Tags: c++, c, linux, shell, kernel

I am trying to write a shell for Linux in C and/or C++. What functions should I use to interact with the kernel? Someone said to use `system()`, but I think it calls the shell, which would result in infinite recursion. Someone else said something about `fork()` and `exec()`.

Obviously a good shell needs some way to access the file system. I assume the kernel provides an interface of some sort for this, does it not? How would I read the output from the kernel? Is it text or integers?

Is there a place where I can find good documentation on the necessary functions? Is there a particular man page or source code file that I sould read?

Comment: You could also study the source code of simple free shells like e.g. sash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The kernel provides a set of 'system calls' for low-level process execution and file system access. Process execution is generally done using [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) and one of the [`exec()` family calls](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/execv.html). I/O can be done with calls such as [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html), [`stat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stat.html), [`opendir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/opendir.html), etc.

A list of most of the more-portable calls (both C library and system calls) can be found at the [Open Group Base Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/) (click 'system interfaces'). There are some linux-specific ones as well - the ones intended for ordinary use will be documented in section 2 of the manual pages (`ls /usr/share/doc/man/man2` or `man 2 somefunction`).

Answer (score 3):

A good place to start is an operating systems textbook.  I would recommend the "[dinosaur book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471250600)" by Silberschatz et al.  Another good resource is Prof. Dave Hollinger's class page at RPI for his operating systems course.  The lecture slides are online, including one lecture on writing a shell.  There's also a homework assignment there on writing a basic shell that you can check out.

http://cgi2.cs.rpi.edu/~hollingd/opsys/opsys.php

A shell is a very complicated program that can't really be described in a StackOverflow answer.  However, these resources should point you in the right direction.

Comment: These resources look useful. There is also another educational resource at [http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dab/cs3100.html](http://icarus.cs.weber.edu/~dab/cs3100.html)

Answer (score 1):

The list of [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) understood by the [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) is documented in the [syscalls(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/syscalls) man page.

A shell usually don't interface to all of them. A shell is usually mostly concerned about system calls impacting the processes it can run. For example, a shell usually don't need to call (by itself) the [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) or [mprotect](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect) syscalls (even if the implementation of `malloc` probably calls `mmap`).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to know what all functionalities the existing shell provides :

1. Forking executables and executing them.

2. An interpreter, for shell scripts.

3. Few built-in commands like cd etc..

4. And many more things..I would suggest to read some UNIX OS book

If you just want to run commands in your new shell .. then you have to just fork and execute(or you can make it threaded) the already existing executables at "/bin" , "/usr/bin" etc.

If its just a hobby project I would recommend you to use Python subprocess module

Comment: Google and you will find lots of interesting stuffs.. Trust me :)